# Access to host property with AS3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, proxy, system, host

I'm looking for equivalent of this code in Flex AS3.

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

This is a java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting you right, you want to declare global property in action script? If yes, then the following code should suit your needs:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['http.proxyHost'] = "127.0.0.1";
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['http.proxyPort'] = "80";
```

Then you can access them like this:

```
var host:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['http.proxyHost'];
var port:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['http.proxyPort'];
```